# Combining two IF condition in excel for a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help in combining two IF condition statements in excel. Both are working fine, just that when I try to combine them then I'm getting error. Below are the conditions:

=IF(AND(F19="No", NOT(OR(ISBLANK(B36),ISBLANK(B37),ISBLANK(D36),ISBLANK(D37),ISBLANK(B40),ISBLANK(D39),ISBLANK(F39),ISBLANK(D40),ISBLANK(F40),ISBLANK(B43),ISBLANK(B44),ISBLANK(B48),ISBLANK(B49),ISBLANK(B50),ISBLANK(B51),ISBLANK(B52)))),"Section Complete","Section Incomplete")

=IF(AND(F19="Yes", NOT(OR(ISBLANK(B36),ISBLANK(B37),ISBLANK(D36),ISBLANK(D37),ISBLANK(B40),ISBLANK(D39),ISBLANK(F39),ISBLANK(D40),ISBLANK(F40),ISBLANK(B43),ISBLANK(B44),ISBLANK(B48),ISBLANK(B49),ISBLANK(B50),ISBLANK(B51),ISBLANK(B52),ISBLANK(D43),ISBLANK(D44),ISBLANK(D45),ISBLANK(D46),ISBLANK(D47),ISBLANK(D48),))),"Section Complete","Section Incomplete")

Please help me in combining them.

Thanks in advance, Krishna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... I didn't try and make it prettier / more efficient - I just used your original formulas, but this should do what you want:

```
=IF(OR(AND(F19="No", NOT(OR(ISBLANK(B36),ISBLANK(B37),ISBLANK(D36),ISBLANK(D37),ISBLANK(B40),ISBLANK(D39),ISBLANK(F39),ISBLANK(D40),ISBLANK(F40),ISBLANK(B43),ISBLANK(B44),ISBLANK(B48),ISBLANK(B49),ISBLANK(B50),ISBLANK(B51),ISBLANK(B52)))),AND(F19="Yes", NOT(OR(ISBLANK(B36),ISBLANK(B37),ISBLANK(D36),ISBLANK(D37),ISBLANK(B40),ISBLANK(D39),ISBLANK(F39),ISBLANK(D40),ISBLANK(F40),ISBLANK(B43),ISBLANK(B44),ISBLANK(B48),ISBLANK(B49),ISBLANK(B50),ISBLANK(B51),ISBLANK(B52),ISBLANK(D43),ISBLANK(D44),ISBLANK(D45),ISBLANK(D46),ISBLANK(D47),ISBLANK(D48))))),"Section Complete","Section Incomplete")
```

Hope this does the trick!!

Answer (score 0):

You could just as simple replace the "Section incomplete" in the first No-IF, by replacing it with the Yes-IF.

```
=IF(AND(F19="No";NOT(OR(ISBLANK(B36);ISBLANK(B37);ISBLANK(D36);ISBLANK(D37);ISBLANK(B40);ISBLANK(D39);ISBLANK(F39);ISBLANK(D40);ISBLANK(F40);ISBLANK(B43);ISBLANK(B44);ISBLANK(B48);ISBLANK(B49);ISBLANK(B50);ISBLANK(B51);ISBLANK(B52))));"Section Complete";IF(AND(F19="Yes";NOT(OR(ISBLANK(B36);ISBLANK(B37);ISBLANK(D36);ISBLANK(D37);ISBLANK(B40);ISBLANK(D39);ISBLANK(F39);ISBLANK(D40);ISBLANK(F40);ISBLANK(B43);ISBLANK(B44);ISBLANK(B48);ISBLANK(B49);ISBLANK(B50);ISBLANK(B51);ISBLANK(B52);ISBLANK(D43);ISBLANK(D44);ISBLANK(D45);ISBLANK(D46);ISBLANK(D47);ISBLANK(D48);)));"Section Complete";"Section Incomplete"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying with some COUNTA functions like this:

`=IF(AND(COUNTA(B36,B37,D36,D37,B40,D39,F39,D40,F40,B43,B44,B48:B52)=16,OR(F19="No",AND(F19="Yes",COUNTA(D43:D48)=6))),"Section Complete","Section Incomplete")`

That should combine the two formulas without repetition